# Selecting particular xml records with a condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have set of price records with different suppliers name.I want to take the latest price for a supplier by date.Please help

```
<price_record>
<price>222.5</price>
<price_date>20060724</price_date>
<price_supplier_name>ABC ></price_supplier_name>
<seq_num>1</seq_num>
</price_record>

  <price_record>
  <price>382.5</price>
  <price_date>20080725</price_date>    
  <price_supplier_name>ABC  </price_supplier_name>
  <seq_num>2</seq_num>
  </price_record>

  <price_record>
  <price>88.58</price>
  <price_date>20060928</price_date>    
  <price_supplier_name>YZ ></price_supplier_name>
  <seq_num>3</seq_num>
  </price_rec

  <price_record>
  <price>78</price>
  <price_date>20060928</price_date>    
  <price_supplier_name>YZ ></price_supplier_name>
  <seq_num>3</seq_num>
  </price_record>
```

I want to get unique Price(by latest date) for each supplier.

Comment: You need to learn about Muenchian grouping. Start here:http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

Given this XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <price_record>
        <price>222.5</price>
        <price_date>20060724</price_date>
        <price_supplier_name>ABC</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>1</seq_num>
    </price_record>

    <price_record>
        <price>382.5</price>
        <price_date>20080725</price_date>
        <price_supplier_name>ABC</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>2</seq_num>
    </price_record>

    <price_record>
        <price>88.58</price>
        <price_date>20060927</price_date>
        <price_supplier_name>YZ</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>3</seq_num>
    </price_record>

    <price_record>
        <price>78</price>
        <price_date>20060928</price_date><!-- modified  -->
        <price_supplier_name>YZ</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>3</seq_num>
    </price_record>
</root>
```

and this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="Suppliers">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/price_record/price_supplier_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="price_record">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="following::price_record[price_date &gt; current()/price_date]/price_supplier_name = current()/price_supplier_name or preceding::price_record[price_date &gt; current()/price_date]/price_supplier_name = current()/price_supplier_name"/>

                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($Suppliers, current()/price_supplier_name) and preceding::price_record[price_date &gt; current()/price_date]/price_supplier_name = current()/price_supplier_name"/>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <price_record>
        <price>382.5</price>
        <price_date>20080725</price_date>
        <price_supplier_name>ABC</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>2</seq_num>
    </price_record>
    <price_record>
        <price>78</price>
        <price_date>20060928</price_date>
        <!-- modified  -->
        <price_supplier_name>YZ</price_supplier_name>
        <seq_num>3</seq_num>
    </price_record>
</root>
```

Comment: The requirement is to get only one single latest record for a supplier

Comment: @ Joel M. Lamsen, your answer is useful ,but one thing is we need to take only the latest of each group

Comment: @user3309204, I have edited my answer. Please check if this answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Is there any feedback?

Comment: Actually I am not much familiar with xsl:apply-templates ,copy etc. So I have taken the logic of your code and applied in my own way.Unfortunately I couldn't fix the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match ="price_records">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="price_record" group-by="price_supplier_name">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:sort select="price_date" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Getting compile error says that the element "for-each-group" is invalid in xslt.

Comment: @user3309204 It is invalid in XSLT 1.0. Please add the xslt-1.0 tag to your question.

Comment: Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but you use a 2.0 function. You will want to change that to not confuse anyone not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll go ahead and post an answer. The following XSLT code uses Muenchian grouping in XSL 1.0 to get *a* unique price that is the most recent for each supplier. I read your question a couple times, and unless I missed something, you only asked for the most recent price, but did not clarify what you want when two different prices occur on the same date for a single supplier... which is the case for the "YZ" supplier. But since the XML isn't complete anyway, I assumed it was a typo for the sake of simplicity. Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="supplierToRecord" match="price_record" use="price_supplier_name"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="price_record[generate-id()=generate-id(key('supplierToRecord', price_supplier_name)[1])]">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('supplierToRecord', price_supplier_name)">
            <xsl:sort select="price_date" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As you said it is a typo of my actual xslt.

Comment: My issue is not fully resolved ,however it helped me to know how to proceed this kind of requirement.